# dynamically appended Web Font Loader - how to check if script already exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, fonts, google-font-api

I am building presentation builder with an option to choose fonts. user can choose font from the list and this triggers the font loader with chosen font. The problem is it is appending new script every time.

```
$(document).on('click', '.fonts-container ul li', function(){  
    var $el = $(this);
    var fontName = $el.data('fontname');
    $(this).closest(".editor").find('.text2').css('font-family', fontName);
    $("#data-store").data("text").push($el.data('fontname'));
    WebFontConfig = {
        google: { families: $("#data-store").data("text")
      }  
    }
    fontLoad();
});


var fontLoad = function() {
  var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
        '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'true';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);  
}
```

How can I check if this script already exist and if so just trigger the http request to load new set of fonts?

Answer (score 0):

I'm decently sure you can just add an ID to the script, such as `font-script`, and then check if it exists again when clicked:

```
var fontLoad = function() {
    if(document.getElementById('font-script').length) return;
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.id = 'font-script';
    ...the rest of your code
```